# Tidal Cycles cabal install failure

Tags: installation, cabal

I'm trying to install tidal cycles to program live music - but am running into errors when running cabal install tidal via cmd

Logs:

Resolving dependencies...
Downloading  mwc-random-0.14.0.0
Starting     network-3.0.1.0
Downloaded   mwc-random-0.14.0.0
Starting     mwc-random-0.14.0.0
Failed to install network-3.0.1.0
Build log ( C:\Users\Moz\AppData\Roaming\cabal\logs\ghc-8.6.3\network-3.0.1.0-KyWTN8R07Nk13a65qAf8xd.log ):
Configuring network-3.0.1.0...
cabal.exe: The package has a './configure' script. If you are on Windows, This
requires a Unix compatibility toolchain such as MinGW+MSYS or Cygwin. If you
are not on Windows, ensure that an 'sh' command is discoverable in your path.
cabal: Leaving directory 'D:\Temp\TMP\cabal-tmp-7496\network-3.0.1.0'
Building     mwc-random-0.14.0.0
Completed    mwc-random-0.14.0.0
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
hosc-0.17-Gak1PuEPYn3IoGtbGyt03X depends on hosc-0.17 which failed to install.
network-3.0.1.0-KyWTN8R07Nk13a65qAf8xd failed during the configure step. The
exception was:
ExitFailure 1
tidal-1.0.7-G7PMBDSlH0ZK2qQ3UODU3y depends on tidal-1.0.7 which failed to
install.

Cheers for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All good, needed to add these lines to config file:
extra-prog-path: C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.6.3\msys\usr\bin
extra-lib-dirs: C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.6.3\mingw\lib
extra-include-dirs: C:\Program Files\Haskell Platform\8.6.3\mingw\include

Cheers anyhow